# Traffic routing has issue on AWS but works on Minikube using below config

Tags: amazon-web-services, istio

Using this config Getting No healthy upstream Http 503. If i just remove subset everything works perfectly fine.

## Source: ccgf-helm-umbrella-chart/charts/ccgf-cdlg-app/templates/service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
    service: ccgf-cdlg-app
  name: ccgf-cdlg-app
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  selector:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

    ---
```

## Source: ccgf-helm-umbrella-chart/charts/ccgf-cdlg-app/templates/deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ccgf-cdlg-app-production
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
  labels:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
    version: production
spec:
  replicas: 1

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ccgf-cdlg-app
      version: production
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ccgf-cdlg-app
        version: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: edc-ccgf-ui-app:1.37
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ccgf-cdlg-app
        ports:
        - name: ccgf-cdlg-app
          containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 20
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: spinnakerrepoaccess
```

---

## Source: ccgf-helm-umbrella-chart/charts/ccgf-cdlg-app/templates/deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ccgf-cdlg-app-canary
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
  labels:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
    version: canary
spec:
  replicas: 1

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ccgf-cdlg-app
      version: canary
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ccgf-cdlg-app
        version: canary
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: edc-ccgf-ui-app:1.38
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: ccgf-cdlg-app
        ports:
        - name: ccgf-cdlg-app
          containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 20
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: spinnakerrepoaccess
```

### #virtual Service

```
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: ccgf-cdlg-app
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  hosts:
    - '*'
  gateways:
    - ccgf-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /cdlg-edc-devci/frontend
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: ccgf-cdlg-app.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
            subset: production
          retries:
            attempts: 3
            perTryTimeout: 2s
            retryOn: 'gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream'
          weight: 50
        - destination:
            host: ccgf-cdlg-app.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
            subset: canary
          retries:
            attempts: 3
            perTryTimeout: 2s
            retryOn: 'gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream'
          weight: 50
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /static
      rewrite:
        uri: /static
      route:
        - destination:
            host: ccgf-cdlg-app.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
          retries:
            attempts: 3
            perTryTimeout: 2s
            retryOn: 'gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream'
```

### #Destination rule

```
kind: DestinationRule
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: ccgf-cdlg-app
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  host: ccgf-cdlg-app
  subsets:
    - labels:
        version: canary
      name: canary
    - labels:
        version: production
      name: production
```

---

## Source: ccgf-helm-umbrella-chart/charts/ccgf-gateway/templates/gateway.yaml

```
kind: Gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: ccgf-gateway
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - '*'
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
  selector:
    release: istio-custom-ingress-gateways
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a reproduction based on your yamls and everything works just fine, the only thing I have is basic istio ingress gateway instead of the custom one.

---

For start could you please change Host in [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) and check if it works then?

It should be

`ccgf-cdlg-app.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local` instead of `ccgf-cdlg-app`

---

Did you enable [istio injection](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/) in your cdlg-edc-devci namespace?

You can check it with `kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection`

It should be

```
NAME             STATUS   AGE   ISTIO-INJECTION
cdlg-edc-devci   Active   37m   enabled
```

---

And the reproduction yamls.

---

```
kubectl create namespace cdlg-edc-devci
kubectl label namespace cdlg-edc-devci istio-injection=enabled
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ccgf-cdlg-app
      version: production
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ccgf-cdlg-app
        version: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http-dep1
          containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ccgf-cdlg-app
      version: canary
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ccgf-cdlg-app
        version: canary
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http-dep2
          containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx2 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
  labels:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http-svc
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: ccgf-cdlg-app
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  gateways:
  - ccgf-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - name: production
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /cdlg-edc-devci/frontend
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: can
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: nginx.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: prod
      weight: 50
  - name: canary
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /s
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: can
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginxdest
  namespace: cdlg-edc-devci
spec:
  host: nginx.cdlg-edc-devci.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: prod
    labels:
      version: production
  - name: can
    labels:
      version: canary
```

---

```
kind: Gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: ccgf-gateway
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - '*'
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubu
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 3000"]
```

---

Some results from ubuntu pod

---

> curl -v external_istio-ingress_gateway_ip/cdlg-edc-devci/frontend

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx2

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx1
```

> curl -v external_istio-ingress_gateway_ip/s

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx2
```

I hope it answer your question. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: After more deugging we found that issue was with pilot pod. It had some stale routing entries. After restarting the pod everything worked properly. Anyways Thanks to you for debugging this.